# How do I make Crashplan back up my Google Drive folder?

Tags: backup, crashplan

Google Drive doesn't keep version of files and it doesn't keep backups over 30 days. How do I backup my Google Drive folder on Crashplan? It's just files on my computer. It should back up just like any other files. The folder is selected, but it doesn't show any subfolders. In the restore, it only shows a few files (G-Docs), but none of the subfolders. I have 1.6GB, 3.5k files, 124 folders in my Google Drive.

Notice the triangle is missing for Google Drive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you synchronize the google drive?

Comment: I use regular Google Drive software and it syncs fine. But it doesn't have all the features of Crashplan like file versioning or 6-month+ restores.

Answer (score 0):

I back my Google Drive up with Cra$hplan. There is no point in it, just too lazy to fix it. Are you sure that it has been backed up? As shown below mine has the triangle. Are you sure that you have synchronized?

[image: Cra$hplan Application]

*Now test and see if it works.* Google Drive is directory structure on your local machine that is replicated with a remote server. No magic! You can see the **.tmp.drivedownload** folder where the files are created on download.

```
L_User@LT08:/mnt/c/Users/L_User/Google Drive$ ls -al 
total 67858534
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Oct  3 16:06 .
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Oct  3 06:41 ..
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Aug 29  2016 Apps
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Aug 19  2016 Docs
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Oct 29  2016 Movies
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Aug 29  2016 Outlook
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Nov  1  2016 Screenshots
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Aug 30  2016 SD Card
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Aug 26  2016 Sent files
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Aug 17  2016 Shares
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Jul 15 17:26 .tmp.drivedownload
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root     4096 Jul 15 17:25 Voice Recordings
```

Run a *Cra$hplan restore* to a *different location*, your desktop - **only the Google Drive folder**. When the restore completes, open the directory check what you have in there. You can safely delete the folder from your desktop when you are done.

Comment: I was poking around the internet to figure out how to mount GoogleDrive as a Network drive.  I found VSubst.exe, it works very well for Dropbox as well, be careful where you get it from.

Comment: Very strange. I don't believe that Google Drive _has_ been backed up to Crashplan. I'll add more screen shots later. I also see you are on Linux, so maybe there is a difference in the Crashplan clients?

Comment: I am using Linux on Windows, it is a windows extension for developers. Start->run->bash.  What you are seeing is "Windows Subsystem for Linux:"  `uname -a
Linux LT08 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I am in the final days of replacing Cra$shplan, they have announced that all end user accounts will be converted to business, the fees will increase for less storage. I have 4TB in their cloud, 15Mbps uploads over 100mbps FiOS. Replacing it with 40GB SSD./8GB RAM system rescued from my neighbors trash, attached to 32TB SATA array on USB3, running OpenMediaVault over a 1Gbps intranet. Backup speeds up to 500Mbps on wireles A/C. **pushing USB3 to the limit**. I used to have the array hooked up to an HP Proliant G7 which was hammered to the point of uselessness trying to manage the storage array.

Comment: @BDBeers: out of curiosity where are you migrating?

Comment: @tukan I am migrating too. https://alternativeto.net/software/crashplan/ I'm considering Duplicati + Dreamhost. Versioning, Encryption, Retention, Scheduling. Have to pay for Dreamhost servers though, unless you set up Tahoe with 10 friends.

Comment: @chloe: thank you. I don`t have good experience with dreamhost. Im glad I just got away from them. Anyways thank you for the tip.